# sql union error

Tags: mysql, sql

I always get the "the used select statements have different number of columns" error.

```
select Sublessee_uname, Sublessee_fname, Sublessee_mname, Sublessee_fname from sublessee
union
select Sublessee_space, Sublessee_product from space_reserve
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory. In the first `SELECT` you have **4 columns**, whilst in the second you have **2 columns**. In order to use `UNION`, the number of columns in both `SELECT`s must match.

Answer (score 0):

In a `union` the number of column need to match. Try

```
select Sublessee_uname, Sublessee_fname, Sublessee_mname, Sublessee_fname
from sublessee     
union
select Sublessee_space, Sublessee_product, null, null
from space_reserve
```

[Simplified Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92d56/1)

Comment: i only want to show the data of the sublessee_uname, sublesse_fname, Sublessee_mname, Sublessee_lname PLUS the data of sublessee_space, Sublessee_product. and the query only shows the sublessee records

Comment: It should work. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92d56/1). If it does not work for you then enhance this example please to show your real problem

Answer (score 0):

**In Union Case no of columns should be same in query
For you reference check this** [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of your comments, it seems to me that you need a *join* of two tables rather than a *union* thereof.

And often, to join two tables, one of them must have a column or columns referencing the other. As the columns shown in your query do not seem to contain among them the right ones to use in the join condition and I don't know at this point what other columns your two tables possess, I'm going two assume that there's a `Sublessee_Id` column in both tables. And the query to retrieve the required data would then look something like this:

```
SELECT
  s.Sublessee_uname,
  s.Sublessee_fname,
  s.Sublessee_mname,
  s.Sublessee_fname,
  r.Sublessee_space,
  r.Sublessee_product
FROM sublessee s
LEFT JOIN space_reserve r  /* or, depending on the requirements,
                              INNER JOIN space_reserve r */
  ON s.Sublessee_Id = r.Sublessee_Id
;
```

If you want to learn more about JOIN syntax, you can try this manual page:

- [`JOIN` Syntax (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)